# How to pass from and body as parameters in Twilio SMS webhook URL

Tags: sms, twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

I have a Twilio SMS number configured to send a request to a WebServer via a Webhook URL. What I am trying to understand is can I pass the 'from' phone number and 'SMS body' as parameters in the Webhook URL?

For example:

```
https://myserver/v1/sms?phoneNo='FROM'&message='MSG'
```

I understand I can extract this information from the Body on the server but this would require additional coding, testing, deployment etc... on the web server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Keep the URL as `https://myserver/v1/sms` (Twilio will add the parameters for you when it makes the request)
- To the right of the webhook url field, change in the drop-down from `HTTP POST` to `HTTP GET`

[image]

- Save

---

With this configuration, Twilio will send the parameters with its request as  URL query parameters.

The names for the two parameters mentioned in your question are

- `From` (The phone number that sent the message) and
- `Body` (The text body of the message.).

Other parameters are: `MessageSid`, `SmsSid`, `AccountSid`, `MessagingServiceSid`, `To`, `NumMedia`

You can read more here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application

---

> If you'd like to have your own names for the GET parameters

then, probably the easiest would be to use Twilio Studio with a `HTTP REQUEST` widget and configure the phone number with `Studio Flow` instead of `Webhook`.

[image]

The `HTTP REQUEST` will let you make a `GET` request and add your own parameters to it.

[image]

For the values you would use `{{trigger.message.From}}` for your `phoneNo` and `{{trigger.message.Body}}` for your `message`.

[image]

You can read more about Twilio Studio's widgets here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#http-request